# Docker cannot find file that clearly is there

Tags: python, docker

I want to run a python server from inside a docker container. The last line in my Dockerfile is `ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv", "run", "python", "main.py"]`. When running the container docker tells me that it `can't open file '/usr/src/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

However if I run the container interactively with `winpty docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh my_container:latest -s` I can see with `ls` that the file is clearly where it is supposed to be, and running `pipenv run python main.py` starts the server with no errors. I've tried using an absolute path to the file and that didn't change anything.

I am clueless how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please add the Dockerfile to your question.

Comment: Please show how you run the container when it fails.